# Do I need a form-group for every input/select option or is one for all of them enough?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
```

Do I need a form-group for every single input/select option or is one for all of them enough? I still need an answer to this.